# Ionic 3 Angular 4: Visual Studio Code or WebStorm?

Tags: cordova, ionic2, visual-studio-code, webstorm, ionic3

With latest update, I want to make application in Ionic 3 (i.e Angular 4). Before this I have used both IDEs as Angular development in code and made Ionic 2 (i.e Angular 2) app with WebStorm.

I am not able to decide what would be the right choice to get going with Ionic development and Cordova plugins support.

Visual Studio Code or WebStorm ?

Any Suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: either will work, which makes this question opinion based, and off topic here.

Comment: @claies - this might be opinion based question but dont see any problem in getting any opinions. I dont understand why this is off topic for you.

Comment: you should read the [help] section if you don't understand, Particularly [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) #4:  "4.Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: or the description of the Primarily Opinion Based close reason: "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionic and Angular both are running on top of Microsoft Typescript.Visual studio code is also from Microsoft.If you need to test the `latest and greatest` features of `Typescript` then you must go with the `Microsoft Visual Studio code`.That tool has a nightly build version too. If you have a hurry to test, not yet released typescript features then you can do that too with Visual studio code.My prime choice is **Visual studio code**. It is an awesome tool, especially for the front end developments.

[**Visiual studio code**](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode) is **free** and **open source**.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense to me why code would be better for this. Though i have doubt for cordova plugins support in code.

Comment: What is the issue with Cordova and code? You just need to install it and use it.What else do you expect from it?